# How to execute npm run command forever

Tags: node.js, forever

[image]
I have an application with `angular` in the font
end and `node.js` in the back end. I have deployed the application in a same server. My `angular` one is running forever. But back end was not running forever.
From local I used to run the back end using

`npm run dev-server`

After some research I found that installing forever server can be the way. But when running the below command in the server I am getting error

This is the command:
In unix server
`sudo forever -c "npm run dev-server" ./`

But it gives me error.

Can anyone suggest how to run the backend ``` node.js`` application forever with ```npm run` command.

Comment: I know its a **forever** specific question but you could use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) which is good alternative to **forever**. Another option is [`systemd`](https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/) for the ask.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use Forever.js? It's a CLI tool that basically do that. The link for it is: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

When i need to make sure the server is always on, i use it.

Comment: Yes I try to use forever but when executing npm  run getting some error.

Comment: Can you post the error mensagem when you using forever?

Comment: ubuntu@ip-10-245-1-43:~/my-app-1.0.0$ forever start -c "npm run dev-server" /home/ubuntu/my-app-1.0.0/backend
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms

Comment: Did you try withou the 'dev-server' part?

Comment: Yes ..Same issue

Comment: And with --minUptime parameter? Remembering that this parameter uses time in milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You should not force to maintain the server on, since it won't work. A web server listens for connections in a socket and should never stop, if it's stopping is because some error.

You shouldn't use a dev server for production. If you need to publish a web page you need a http server.

Since you are working in node, I would recommend [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/).

This is not a hard task and you can develop a server fitted to your needs.

Here you've got a simple example:

```
my_folder
|-server.js
|-public/
```

And the server.js contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(8080);
```

Place your files in the "public" folder. All files in this folder will be served when you ask for them in the browser.

in "my_folder" run "npm install express" and "npm start" and the server will be listening under "localhost:8080".

Comment: I have shared the folder structure of my project and i don't want to modify the structure at it will brings code changes in my project .Please suggest.